# How to get reference of self class?

Tags: javascript

In php,  `self::` can access self class methods even if the class is inherited.

```
<?php
class A {
    public function __construct(){
        echo "A\n";
        $this->foo();
        self::foo();
        echo "\n";
    }
    public function foo(){
        echo 1;
    }
}

class B extends A{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        echo "B\n";
        $this->foo();
        self::foo();
        echo "\n";
    }
    public function foo(){
        echo 2;
    }
}

new B();
// A
// 21
// B
// 22
```

I want to do same operation in JavaScript.

```
class A {
    constructor(){
        this.foo()
        // What code should I write here?

    }
    foo(){
        console.log(1)
    }
}

class B extends A {
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.foo()
    }
    foo(){
        console.log(2)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the specific function from the specific class' prototype and call it setting the current context (`this`):

```
A.prototype.foo.call(this)
```

Though note that I would suggest this is a bad idea, both in PHP and Javascript. Just let the override work its course, that's what it's overridden for.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, must I write class name `A`?  I want to write without specifing class name if it can. I tried `arguments.callee.prorotype.foo.call(this)`, but i got an error because class syntax forces strict mode.

Comment: Yes, you pretty much have to.

Comment: OK. I understand. Thank you.